# how to increase element width to both sides

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "40%"; }, 2000);
```

The code only increase the width on the right side.

```
.sidenav {
  margin-left: 40%;
  height: 0px; 
  width: 20%; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
  padding-left: 60px; 
  transition: 0.7s; 

}
```

This is my CSS of the code

Comment: did you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Center The SideNav Using

```
.sidenav {
margin: auto;
}
```

Then Do The Width

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you set height to 0 in your css. Please try this on.
You should set left and right 0 when place in absolute position to make it in center pos. Only then you will feel width bigger on both side.

```
.sidenav {
  margin:auto;  
  width: 20%; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111; 
  overflow-y: hidden; 
  padding-left: 60px; 
  transition: 0.7s; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Width property does increase the total width, "on both sides". There is no separate right or left width

Comment: but i need to expand it both sides